# Hide an input until a checkbox has been checked

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, input

In the following form how can I hide an `<input>` tag after the `checkbox` and show it when the `checkbox` is checked?

```html
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li>
        <input type="text" name="accountname" style="width:95%" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder="Company Name" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Please fill in your contact information below</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="First Name" />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder="Last Name" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="text" name="address" class="field-style field-split align-left" placeholder="Street # and Name" />
        <select placeholder="Street Type" style="height:33" class="field-style field-split align-center">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Street Type</option>
            <option value="St.">Street</option>
            <option value="Rd.">Road</option>
            <option value="Way">Way</option>
        </select>
        <select placeholder="Direction" style="height:33" class="field-style field-split align-right">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Direction (If Applicable)</option>
            <option value="N">North</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <select placeholder="State" style="height:33" class="field-style field-split align-left">
            <option value="" disabled selected>State</option>
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="Street Name" placeholder="Zip Code" class="field-style field-split align-right" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Telephone Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="tel-number-field" name="tel_no_1" value="" maxlength="4" />-
        <input type="text" class="tel-number-field" name="tel_no_2" value="" maxlength="4" />-
        <input type="text" class="tel-number-field" name="tel_no_3" value="" maxlength="10" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" />
    </li>
    <!-- Hide/show an input element below this checkbox -->
    <input type="checkbox" />
    </br>
    </br>
    <li>
        <button type="submit" style="width:95%">Submit Account</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Hiding and showing sibling elements using only CSS

<sup><sub>(See the code corrections section below for more information on corrections not specified in this section)</sub></sup>

If you want to be able to show and hide an `<input>` tag after the `checkbox`, there is a CSS solution.

Simply append an input tag to the `<li>` tag, then use the CSS [`~` General sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) as in the following code to hide and show the `<input>` tag according to the `:checked` state of the `checkbox`

```css
input[type="checkbox"] ~ input {
    display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ input {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul style="list-style:none"> 
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" /> 
        <br /><br />
        <input type="text">
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

#### Code corrections

The only direct descendant elements allowed within a `<ul>` tag are `<li>` tags.

There is also no such thing as a `</br>` tag, however there is a `<br>` tag with an optional (in HTML4 and HTML5) self-ending flag `<br />`.

This means that the following code should change

```
<ul>
    ...
    <input type="checkbox" />
    </br></br>
    ...
</ul>
```

To the following code

```
<ul>
    ...
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <br /><br />
    </li>
    ....
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just enable and disable the input field using the onchange method

```
enter code here

 <input id = chkbox type="checkbox" onchange= chk_onchange();/>
 <script>
 function chk_onchange(){

 if(document.getElementById("chkbox").checked)
 enable the field
 else
 disable the filed
 }
</script>
```